# JavaFX - alwaysOnTop(boolean) method missing

Tags: javafx

I want to use the `alwaysOnTop(boolean)` method in JavaFX. 
However, the method crops up as undefined. I checked the version of JavaFX and it tells me: **8.0.11-b12**
I think this is the latest one available right now. 
Can anybody please tell me the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`alwaysOnTop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#alwaysOnTopProperty) property was introduced in version 8u20: you need to upgrade to the [latest JDK version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Yes...got the latest one now